# Appending a string to HTML using htmlagiity pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack in C#.
I loaded my html with

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(model.Content);
```

Now, I am generating a string like so:

```
"<div> abc</div><div>xyz</div>"
```

I want to append this string in the above html before saving. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood you just want to join 2 strings. HTML is string, so you have 2 strings.

1. `model.Content`
2. `string myString = "<div> abc</div><div>xyz</div>"`

To join the strings you must simply do:

```
string myNewHTML = model.Content + myString;
```

After that do whatever you want with your text

Load it to HtmlDocument

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(myNewHTML);
```

or save it to file

```
File.WriteAllText(path,myNewHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks.. Thats what i did. But, I wonder if I can append the string to HTML directly without converting the HTML to string

Comment: You not converting html to strin, html is string, if you don't want create new variable just write e.g. File.WriteAllText(path,model.Content + myString);` if you want to add the string to the model.Content then tell us what is the model.Content, is it class?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the HTMLagility pack but I think you should be able to do this by dumping your HTML into a string (there will be a function that does it, something like DumpHTML maybe. Just go through the documentation of the library), append/concatenate your new html-like string, and again run the LoadHtml function to convert the new string into an HTML object.